# iOS Contacts-style button with right navigation arrow

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

Apple built a button within their Contacts app that indicates navigation between views with a forward arrow. None of the standard button settings, navigation or segue options appear to replicate this behavior in a button. Is there a forward compatible way of implementing it?

Image of the button described below

Contacts form button in tableview with forward navigation arrow:
[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: It looks like table view cell disclosure indicator. You can configure this indicator directly from Interface Builder.

Comment: It does look like a disclosure indicator! But when setting that accessory in Interface builder, the location of the indicator seems fixed at the right of the table cell.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom button and use an image for the arrow icon. Or implement it at a `UITableViewCell` which has a similar arrow (`UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator`).

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewStyles/TableViewCharacteristics.html

Comment: custom button + image isn't forward compatible, and accessories have a fixed location at the right of the table cell I think!

Comment: What do you mean by "forward compatible" exactly?

Comment: if there was a design change to `UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator`, using the true `UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator` rather than an image would change along with the indicator design rather than having to go through the process of having to deploy a new image to the custom button.